# How do I allow specific (uncodesigned) programs to access certain keychain items without password?

Tags: password, keychain, python

I use the python `keyring` module to interact with with macOS Keychain, and I got a prompt to enter my login password to allow access (which I always click "Always Allow") every time I run my script.

[image]

As you can see from the Keychain Access screenshot above, `python` is in the `always allow` list, why am I asked to enter the password then?

The python executable is not codesigned, how do I allow a specific program like `/usr/local/bin/python3` to access certain items in the keychain without a password?